# Change look of image results thumbnails

Tags: css, image, thumbnails

http://protected-river-1861.herokuapp.com/ Link.

When a search is conducted, all results come back with different sizes, all clumped together and generally looking pretty shabby. Please note that I'm a complete beginner, and I'm not enrolled on any courses, just a (new) hobby.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for making them look better (uniform size, spaces between them, borders, shadows etc)?

```
<input id="search-term" type="text">
<button id="go-search"></button>
<div id="search-results"></div>
<div style="width: 150px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div id="branding"></div>
```

CSS:

```
function findImagesOnGoogle(options) {  
$(options.container).empty();
$(options.container).append($("<p>").text("Searching..."));

var imageSearch = new google.search.ImageSearch();
imageSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, function() {
google.search.Search.getBranding('branding');
$(options.container).empty();
for (var i = 0; i < imageSearch.results.length; i++) {
  var result = imageSearch.results[i];      
  var img = $("<img>");
  img.attr('src', result.tbUrl);
  img.data('url', result.url);
  img.appendTo(options.container);
  }
  }, null);
  imageSearch.setResultSetSize(8);
  imageSearch.execute(options.keywords);  
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Can anyone point me in the right direction for making them look better (uniform size, spaces between them, borders, shadows etc)?` may be a bit vague for the scope of SO, do you have an example of the desired output, or a clear, specific explanation (e.g. if borders- what color, size etc?)?

Comment: Hi, I didn't want to be specific because I didn't want people to think I simply wanted the work done for me. I would like blue borders around images that appear the same size on the page, and space between each one so they aren't clumped together.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the image sizes, apply a border and add padding to separate them using the below CSS:

```
#search_results img{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
#search_results img:not(:last-child){
    padding:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

With that in mind, you may want to consider not using `img` tags but setting the images as the `background-image` for (e.g.) `div` tags, this gives you more control over scaling them using, e.g. `background-size:cover;` and/or `background-position:center center;`

e.g:

Change:

```
  var img = $("<img>");
  img.attr('src', result.tbUrl);
```

To:

```
  var img = $("<div>");
  img.css('background-image', 'url('+result.tbUrl+')');
```

And use the CSS:

```
#search_results div{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
}
#search_results div:not(:last-child){
    padding:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: After I tried that the results simply do not appear anymore.

Comment: Specifically which part did you try? I know when I was learning I found it helpful to try one part at a time- try to work out what it does, then when you get to a bit which doesn't work, see if you can see why - often block copying code can cause a fair few unforseen issues

Comment: I changed the bit of code on the 'support.js' tab in sublime text, then added the CSS to application.css.

Since the results aren't showing up at all, I assume it's due to the google image search code and not the CSS. Am I right?